# Use reactivesearch to query multiple indices

Tags: reactivesearch

I realize that one can use ReactiveBase to setup a connection to an index and then, use the components to query and return information from that index.

Is there a way to bind to multiple indices and search on a field across them or return results that are a 'merge' of fields from these multiple indices?

Answer (score 4):

In order to query multiple indices [ReactiveBase](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html) can accept comma separated values in the `app` prop. Example:

```
<ReactiveBase
  app="index1,index2"
  ...
>
  ...
</ReactiveBase>
```

Answer (score 2):

thanks to [siddharthlatest](https://github.com/siddharthlatest), it is possible by providing multiple comma-separated indices - [reference](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/issues/408).

It has been reflected in the ReactiveBase [documentation](https://opensource.appbase.io/reactive-manual/getting-started/reactivebase.html) as well.